# Easier way to solve the integration

Tags: integration

I often need to solve a type of integral which is :

$$\int x \   \sin ( n_1 x) \ \sin (n_2 x)  \ dx $$
$n_1$ and $n_2$ are integers.

where the $n_1 $ and $n_2$ are the integer number.
The way I solve this integral is to break down the $\sin  n_1 x \sin n_2 x $ first using formula  $\cos C - \cos D$ and then take the partial integration.

Is there any easy way to solve this integral?

Comment: You already have the best way to integrate this function. No easier way!

Comment: You can generalise this method to arbitrary $n_1$ and $n_2$ to get this result from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+xsin(n_1x)sin(n_2x)).

Comment: Listen to @KaviRamaMurthy